# Should I be worried about sudden shut down?

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown

I have a laptop that has literally two seconds of battery life, so it is plugged in all the time. Sometimes it gets unplugged, stays on for a second or so, and then shuts down. The hard drive makes an awful noise. If this happens enough, will the hard drive fail?

Comment: It's not good to shut down a computer suddenly.  Will eventually result in disk corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Sudden power failure will cause file corruption and physical damage to the hard drive when the system is not properly shut down.

If the hard drive is making bad noises, you need to **BACK UP YOUR DATA NOW!**

Comment: Also may be related to temperature, also not a good reason for shutdown.

Comment: @JeffF. What does temperature have to do with it? The question states specifically the battery does not hold a charge and "Sometimes it gets unplugged, stays on for a second or so, and then shuts down."

Comment: I misread, I thought he said it was shutting down while plugged in.